# Datatables JS slow render with deferred rendering

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I'm trying to load about 2,000 records and it takes almost a minute to render. I see the records show up right away but then it takes awhile to load in as paginated. I have the deferred rendering options on but I can't tell if they are even working.

my init:

```
table.dataTable({
    "language": {
            "aria": {
                "sortAscending": ": activate to sort column ascending",
                "sortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
            },
            "emptyTable": "No data available in table",
            "info": "Showing1 _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries1",
            "infoEmpty": "No entries found",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtered1 from _MAX_ total entries)",
            "lengthMenu": "Show _MENU_ entries",
            "search": "Search:",
            "zeroRecords": "No matching records found"
        },
        "bStateSave": true, // save datatable state(pagination, sort, etc) in cookie.
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "deferRender": true,
        "orderClasses": false,


 ......
```

I'm using DataTables version 1.10.2

my php loop:

```
$users=user::get_all($filter);
        if($users){
          foreach($users as $row){
            $customer=user::get_cutomer_name_by_source_id($row['source_id']);
            ?>
            <tr class='odd gradeX'>
              <td><input type='checkbox' class='checkboxes' value='1'/></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['source_id']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $customer; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row["created"])); ?></td>
              <td><?php if($row['login']!=NULL){echo date("m/d/Y",$row['login']);} ?></td>
              <td><?php if($row['active']==1){echo "Yes";}else{echo "No";} ?></td>
              <td><?php echo user::get_role_name($row['rid']); ?></td>
              <td><?php 
                if($row['cash_incentive']==1){echo "Cash";}else{echo "Regular";} ?>
                </td>
              <td><a href='user-edit?uid="<?php echo $row['uid']; ?>"'>View </a></td>
              <td><a href='switch?email=<?php echo $row['email']; ?>'> Switch</a></td>
              <td><input type='checkbox' name='email-list[]' value='<?php echo $row['email']; ?>'></td>
            </tr>   
          <?php }
        }
```

The user::get_all function:

```
public static function get_all($filter=NULL,$limit=NULL){
    global $db;     
    $db->SelectRows("users",$filter, NULL, NULL, TRUE,$limit);
    return $db->RecordsArray(MYSQL_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: What DataTables version are you using?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com I am using version 1.10.2

Comment: How are you populating the table?

Comment: @markpsmith It's populated from a php look of a mysql query I'll update my post with that method

Comment: I don't think `deferRender` will work for you as it's for ajax-sourced data. You're populating the table in the DOM and then applying the datatables plugin to it.  Can you look into populating in it using the API?